# Google App Engine: 405 Method POST is not allowed- when uploading a file

Tags: java, servlets

I have a problem when i attempt to upload a file to my server, an `405 Method POST is not allowed` exception appear, this exception only appear on production not locally,

Here's my servlet that handle's form post request

```
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {


@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/uploadCallback");
    uploadUrl = uploadUrl.substring(uploadUrl.indexOf("_") - 1);

    req.getRequestDispatcher(uploadUrl).forward(req, resp);
  }
}
```

the servlet that handles the request from 'FileUploadServlet '

```
public class FileUploadedCallbackServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    String blobKey = blobs.get(FileUploadInput.FILE_URL).get(0).getKeyString(); // Name of field in form where file name was entered
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.print(blobKey);
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    doPost(req, resp);
  }
}
```

Comment: what error u get ?

Comment: @AmitK "405 Method POST is not allowed"

Comment: 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL